# How to classify a stationary point in a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

Le'ts say I have a local minimum at (-1, -1) and the Hessian matrix Hf(-1, -1) is \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.

I have used Taylor Approximation to obtain f(x,y) = $(x+1)^2$ + $(y+1)^4$

I am wondering if this function I obtained satisfies the above criteria (having a local minimum at (-1, -1)).

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it does satisfy the criteria, because changing $x$ a little bit will increase $(x+1)^2$, and changing $y$ a little bit will increase $(y+1)^4$.

Comment: yu can use the second derivative test

Comment: Dr.Sonnharb, what is the second derivative test?

Comment: see here weisstein second derivative test

Comment: What do you mean see here weisstein

Comment: If your function $f(x,y)$ is exactly what you have written, then (pretty clearly) it has a strict local minimum at $(-1,-1)$, but you can't see that by looking at the Hessian, you have to look at the function itself. But it's not clear to me what you mean by “I have used Taylor Approximation to obtain”.